# I have two arrays, one contains all possible select options and the other selected options that should be 'red' how do I accomplish this?

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp

The controller:

```
    $params = array(
        'fields' => array('Course.id', 'Course.weekstart'),
        'conditions' => array(
            'Course.program_id' => $program_id
        )
    );    
    $paramsflagged = array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Course.course_full' => 1,
            'Course.program_id'  => $program_id         
         ),
         'fields' => array('Course.id', 'Course.weekstart')
    );
    $flaggedcourses = $this->Course->find('list', $paramsflagged);
    $courses = $this->Course->find('list', $params);
    $this->set('courses', $courses);
    $this->set('flaggedcourses', $flaggedcourses);
```

The view generating the select list for all options (using the array courses):

```
<select>
    <?php foreach ($courses as $key => $course): ?> 
        <option id="<?php echo $key;?>">        
            <?php echo $course; ?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach;?> 
</select>
```

Courses array=>

```
Array
(
   [2836] => 4 16:40:00
   [2835] => 3 13:20:00
)
```

FlaggedCourses array=>

```
Array
(
    [2835] => 3 13:20:00
)
```

So what would be the best way to create a new array of select options in that view which can 'add a class' to options that were in the flaggedcourses array?

Answer (score 0):

use a multidimensional array

```
Array
(
   [2836] => array('value'=> '4 16:40:00', 'flagged' => '')
   [2835] => array('value'=> '3 13:20:00', 'flagged' => 'selected')
)

<select>
<?php foreach ($courses as $key => $course): ?>   
<option id="'.$key.'" selected="'.$course['flagged'].'">        
    <?php echo $course['value']; ?>
</option>
<?php endforeach;?> 
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select>
<?php foreach ($courses as $key=>$course): ?> 
    <?php
        if (array_key_exists($key, $flaggedcourses)) {
            $class = ' class="flagged"';
        } else {
            $class = '';
        }
    ?>  
    <option id="<?= $key;?>"<?= $class; ?>>
        <?php echo $course; ?>
    </option>
<?php endforeach;?> 
</select>
```

Comment: where? I merely _copied_ the OP's code and added my if statement. I'm pretty sure there's no syntax error there..

Comment: once the code-block is using alternative PHP syntax, all the control statement MUST be in the same syntax too. that's mean `if (): ... endif;`

Comment: surely you must be new to PHP or using some strange version with rules of which I'm not aware, but you are wrong about that. I assure you, there is nothing syntactically wrong with my code snippet.

Comment: I think maybe you're referring to the _same_ control structure.. For example: `if (): /** code */ }` will throw an error.  likewise, so will: `if () { /** code */ endif;`.  If _that_ is what you meant then yes you're right. otherwise I am right.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
foreach ($courses as $key=>$course):
    if (isset($flaggedcourses[$key])):
        $color = ' style="color:red"';
    else:
        $color = '';
    endif;

    echo <<<option
    <option id="{$key}"{$color}>{$course}</option>
    option;

endforeach;
```