# How can I compare two arrays, then for 'matches' add a class to the outputted select option generated from the new array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of all options that will be in a select box:

```
Array
(
   [2836] => 4 16:40:00
   [2835] => 3 13:20:00
)
```

There is a second array of options that have a particular flag in the DB:

```
Array
(
   [2835] => 3 13:20:00
)
```

How can I compare these two arrays to generate a select list that applies a particular class to the matches found in the arrays? I'd love some help thanks!

The view for my select list which receives the first array:

```
<select>
<?php foreach ($courses as $key=>$course): ?>   
<option id="<?php echo $key;?>">        
    <?php echo $course; ?>
</option>
<?php endforeach;?> 
</select>
```

Comment: Same user here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8261397/i-have-two-arrays-one-contains-all-possible-select-options-and-the-other-select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-intersect.php) to find those values common for both arrays. Then in your foreach loop you can check if the current key (or value) is from matches array.

```
$matches = array_intersect($arr1, $arr2);
```

In the view file:

```
<select>
<?php foreach ($courses as $key=>$course): ?>   
    <option id="<?php echo $key;?>" class="<?php echo isset($matches[$key]) ? 'match' : '' ?>">        
        <?php echo $course; ?>
    </option>
<?php endforeach;?> 
</select>
```

Comment: One more question, the "3" and "4" sections in the array refer to an enum referring to days of the week. Is there a simple way to make it so that the array replaces "1" with "Sunday" "2" with Monday etc. That'd be really sweet :)